# React Native Expo - Recover Android kestore(.jks) file from password and alias

Tags: android, react-native, expo, keystore

I misunderstood the purpose of the android keystore (the .jks file) and deleted the file from my computer. However before deleting it, I saved these 3 values:

1. Keystore password
2. Key alias
3. Key password

Is it possible to recover or regenerate the .jks file from these values?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This can be helpful https://medium.com/@farukcankaya/recover-your-lost-android-keystore-file-633c853bd11f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot recover the Keystore file from Keystore password, Key alias, Key password.
If you have not roll out your app to production yet you can create a new keystore.